# Understanding Incremental Environment in the context of annotation processing in Java

Tags: java, annotation-processing, incremental-compiler

I am confused about what exactly is *incremental environment* in the context of annotation processing in Java. An example is highly appreciated.

The following is a quote from the Javadoc of [Filer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html):

> The file creation methods take a variable number of arguments to allow
> the originating elements to be provided as hints to the tool
> infrastructure to better manage dependencies. The originating elements
> are the types or packages (representing package-info files) which
> caused an annotation processor to attempt to create a new file. For
> example, if an annotation processor tries to create a source file,
> GeneratedFromUserSource, in response to processing
>
> ```java
> @Generate
> public class UserSource {}
> ```
>
> the type element for UserSource should be passed as part of the
> creation method call as in:
>
> ```java
> filer.createSourceFile("GeneratedFromUserSource",
>                        eltUtils.getTypeElement("UserSource"));
> ```
>
> If there are no originating elements, none need to be passed. **This
> information may be used in an incremental environment to determine the
> need to rerun processors or remove generated files. Non-incremental
> environments may ignore the originating element information.**

I understand, for example, in the above example, if `@Generated` is removed, the next time compilation is run the previously generated `GeneratedFromUserSource` will be removed. (Supposedly, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452980/are-filers-originating-elements-useful), some implementations like `com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler` ignore originating elements altogether.) Does this make it incremental? I do not have any example in mind for a *need to rerun* the processor.

To make matters a bit more confusing, I have stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966094/how-to-make-my-own-annotation-processor-incremental) question and apparently, there are three types of processors:

1. dynamic,    2. isolating,    3. aggregation

and incremental processors need to be registered in a different place in META-INF than non-incremental ones. I am currently using `@AutoService` which I [think](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/615) does not support this registration.

Since (mostly) overwriting is not allowed in `Filer`, I would appreciate a clarification on what makes a processor incremental.